# 52 week x-axis gglplot2 starting point

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, time-series

I would like to create a plot similar to the one below. Basically would like x-axis to start at week 35 go to week 52 and then display week 0-34.  Haven't really been able to find a solution. The x-axis always seems to default at week 0. I guess I could use week as.factor and manually set the order but this seems like a lot of work. There must be an easier solution. Hope you can help.

[image: 2019 canada influenza]

Sample dataset. I didn't set it up for a normal distribution....probably should have.

```
set.seed(99)
fludata <-data.frame('year'= '2019', 'week'= seq(1,52,by =1), 'cases' = sample(0:17, 52, replace=T))

ggplot(fludata,aes(x=week, y = cases)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Can you use `week-year` for the x-axis? Then you can use `scale_x_date` and the data should extend from late 2019 to middle 2020?

Comment: Presumably the year is different for weeks 35-52 and 0-34? ggplot doesn't make it easy to make numeric scales go in an arbitrary order. The factor solution is the best way to have complete control. ggplot also has nice options for scales when our values are in a proper date format, but where you just have week and (maybe) year.

Comment: Thanks Ben and MrFlick. I suspect I'll have to write them out as factors.

Comment: I like Ben's `scale_x_date` solution best, but if that doesn't work I'd recommend making it a "cumulative" weeks scale - add 52 to the weeks after the year change, and then you could write a simple label transformation that uses `(x - 1) %% 52 + 1` as the label. (The -1... +1 is needed to show 52 instead of 0.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I was thinking. You can convert the `year` and `week` to a `yearweek` with `tsibble`. You can use `scale_x_yearweek` to define where you want your `date_breaks` and include what information you want in the labels (e.g., `%U` for just the week, or `%Y-%U` for year-week). If you omit the year, you can add the years as separate text directly.

**Edit (2/2/21):** Changed from `scale_x_date` to `scale_x_yearweek`.

```
library(tsibble)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(99)

fludata <-data.frame(
  year = c(rep(2019, 18), rep(2020, 34)), 
  week = c(35:52, 1:34),
  cases = sample(0:17, 52, replace=T)
)

fludata$yr_wk <- yearweek(paste(fludata$year, 'week', fludata$week))

fludata %>% 
  ggplot(aes(yr_wk, cases)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_yearweek(date_breaks="2 weeks", date_labels = "%U")
```

[image: plot with weeks ordered]

Answer (score 0):

Converting the year and week to a time object helps:

```
library(tsibble)
set.seed(99)
fludata <-data.frame('year'= c(rep('2020', 34), rep('2019', 52-34)),
                               'week'= seq(1,52,by =1), 'cases' = sample(0:17, 52, replace=T)) %>% 
  mutate(ym=yearweek(paste(year, 'week', week)))

ggplot(fludata,aes(x=ym, y = cases)) + geom_line()
```

You might want to try adding `scale_x_date(labels=scales::label_date_short())` as well.
[image]